# Integrating real function gives a complex value

Tags: complex, calculus-and-analysis

I want to integrate this quite complicated function

```
Sin[2 Pi n x r0/L]*u[x, (m + 1/2) Pi - (nu I Pi/2), kappa I, nu]
```

over x, where

```
u[x_, alpha_, eta_, nu_] := Sqrt[x]*(Exp[I*alpha]*BesselJ[I*nu, eta*x] + Exp[(-I)*alpha]*BesselJ[(-I)*nu, eta*x])
```

which is a real function for the choice of

```
alpha=(m+1/2) Pi - (nu I Pi/2)
```

I tried performing the integral like

```
   Integrate[Sin[p*x*r0]*Chop[N[u[x, (m + 1/2)*Pi - nu*I*(Pi/2), kappa*I, nu]]], {x, 0, Infinity}, 
    Assumptions -> {Element[nu, Reals], nu > 0, Element[kappa, Reals], Element[r0, Reals], r0 > 0, Element[m, Integers], 
      Element[p, Reals]}, GenerateConditions -> False]
```

where I had to use the `Chop` function since otherwise the resulting function is complex valued (which does not make sense). Is there a way I can do this without having to use the `N` function, since I want my final result not to be full of numerical values of constants (like Pi for instance).

The results look like a complicated combination of `Hypergeometric2F1` and `Gamma` functions and quite similar at first glance. But when I plot them as a function of p, the result without the use of `N` has a clear imaginary part where the result with `N` is purely real.

Comment: Please show your results, with and without the  use of `N` and ``Chop`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: With `foo` set equal to the exact integral, `Block[{m = 1, p = 1, nu = 1, r0 = 1, kappa = 1},
 N[foo, 16]
 ]` yields a real number.

Comment: As an aside:  if you have `nu > 0` in your `Assumptions` you do not also need `Element[nu, Reals]`.  Same goes for `r0`.

Comment: @MichaelE2:  Your code yields `-32.64343638231933 - 14.92964274210490 I` for me.  MM 12.1.1.0 on Mac OS 11.4.

Comment: @MichaelE2 try for instance {m = 0, p = 5, nu = 1, r0 = 1/10, kappa = 1}

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I get `-2.704432460069076 + 0.*10^-16 I` on V12.3.0 (Mac).

Comment: @Polarizedphoton:  On the chance that this is some kind of bug in Mathematica, which version of the software are you using and under what OS?

Comment: @ Polarizedphoton, It would be better to update the question so that people can reproduce the issue(s) you face than to leave just a comment. Also Michael's comment suggests your version number may be relevant, so please include that, too. (`Integrate` is under constant development.)

Comment: @MichaelSeifert I get your result in V12.3 if I remove `GenerateConditions -> False`. I guess we might say it's "half fixed" in V12.3. The `-2.7` result agrees with `NIntegate[..., WorkingPrecision -> 16]`.

Comment: For what it's worth,`FourierSinTransform` applied to `u` should give a result that's closely related to your integral (up to an overall factor.)  It yields a result that is pure imaginary for $p^2 r_0^2 < |\kappa|^2$ and pure real for $p^2 r_0^2 > |\kappa|^2$.

Comment: @MichaelE2:  Ah yes, I had forgotten that I had removed that option.  Mea culpa.  If I include it, I get what appears to be the same graph that I got from `FourierSinTransform`.  It returns `0` exactly at the parameters you chose, presumably because neither of the above conditions on $p$, $r_0$, and $\kappa$ hold in that case.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert: Thank you for your help. My Mathematica was not updated and it seems to work in the new version 12.3.

Comment: In addition to v12.3, I also get the expected results in v12.1.1 and 12.2 (I don't have access to other versions).